# How can i fix this undefined index error im getting in php

Tags: php

Im having a variable issue for my array called $templateVars
i have two files one jokes.php and one jokes.html.php
The php file is for database logic, queries, and all php things
The html.php file is for just html

im trying to send the varaiable $templateVars to the html.php file so it can be used 
However i keep getting the variable undefined error 
Im quite new to php and have been stuck on this for a while now 
I would appreciate any help i can get with this

PHP file 
jokes.php

```
<?php

    require '../template.php';
    $title = 'List';

    if (isset($_SESSION['login']) && $_SESSION['login'] == true) {
        if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {

    $jokes = find($pdo, 'jokes');
            $applications = $pdo->prepare('SELECT count(*) as count FROM applications WHERE jokeId = :jokeId');
        $applications->execute(['jokeId' => $jokes['id']]);
        $applicantNumber = $applications->fetch();
        $categoryList = $pdo->prepare('SELECT * FROM category WHERE id = :id');

        $values = [
            'id' => $jokes['categoryid']
        ];
        $categoryList->execute($values);
        $categoryName = $categoryList->fetch();

        $filterCity = find($pdo, 'jokes');

        $templateVars = array(
            'jokes' => $jokes,
            'category' => $categoryList,
            'applications' => $applications,
            'jokes' => $filterCity,
            'categoryList' => $categoryName,
            'applications' => $applicantNumber
        );
    } else {
        $jokes = find($pdo, 'jokes');
        $output = loadTemplate('../Templates/joListing.html.php', $templateVars);
    }
} else {
    $output = loadTemplate('../Templates/login.html.php', []);
}
require '../Templates/layout.html.php';
```

JOKESLIST.html.php code

```
<main class="sidebar">

    <section class="left">
        <ul>
            <li><a href="/jokes">Jokes</a></li>
            <li><a href="/categories">Categories</a></li>

        </ul>
    </section>

    <section class="right">

<h2>Jokes</h2>

<form action="" method="POST">

        <select name = "mySelect" id ="id">
       <?php foreach ($filterCity as $rows){ ?>
        <option value= " '. <?=$rows['id'];?>. '">'. <?=$rows['location'];?>.</option>;

        <?php } ?>
        </select>
<input type="submit" name="filter" value="filter" />



    <?php       foreach ($jokes as $joke) { ?>


        <table>
        <thead>
        <tr>
        <th>Title</th>
        <th>Salary</th>


            </tr>
            <tr>
            <td><?=$joke['title'];?></td>
            <td><?=$joke['salary'];?></td>
            <td><?=$Categoryname['name'];?></td>



                <td><a style="float: right" href="/applications?id=' . <?=$joke['id'] ;?>. '">View applicants (<?=$applicationNumber ['count'] ;?>)</a></td>

                </tr>


            </thead>
            </table>
            <?php } ?>


</section>
</main>
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is here:

```
        <td><?=$joke['title'];?></td>
        <td><?=$joke['salary'];?></td>
        <td><?=$Categoryname['name'];?></td>
```

And here:
`<option value= " '. <?=$rows['id'];?>. '">'. <?=$rows['location'];?>.</option>;`

and also here:
`<td><a style="float: right" href="/applications?id=' . <?=$joke['id'] ;?>. '">View applicants (<?=$applicationNumber ['count'] ;?>)</a></td>`

Youre trying to call php with just `<?` it should be `<?php`.  and you don't need the `=` sign in the php either.  And also this issue is in a few places

```
        <td><?php $joke['title'];?></td>
        <td><?php $joke['salary'];?></td>
        <td><?php $Categoryname['name'];?></td>
```

and

`<option value= " '. <?php $rows['id'];?>. '">'. <?php $rows['location'];?>.</option>;`

and also here:

`<td><a style="float: right" href="/applications?id=' . <?php $joke['id'] ;?>. '">View applicants (<?php $applicationNumber ['count'] ;?>)</a></td>`

Answer to your other question:

```
<?php

    require '../template.php';
    $title = 'List';

    if (isset($_SESSION['login']) && $_SESSION['login'] == true) {
        if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {

    $jokes = find($pdo, 'jokes');
        $applications = $pdo->prepare('SELECT count(*) as count FROM applications WHERE jokeId = :jokeId');
        $applications->execute(['jokeId' => $jokes['id']]);
        $applicantNumber = $applications->fetch();
        $categoryList = $pdo->prepare('SELECT * FROM category WHERE id = :id');

        $values = [
            'id' => $jokes['categoryid']
        ];
        $categoryList->execute($values);
        $categoryName = $categoryList->fetch();

        $filterCity = find($pdo, 'jokes');

        $templateVars = array(
            'jokes' => $jokes,
            'category' => $categoryList,
            'applications' => $applications,
            'jokes' => $filterCity,
            'categoryList' => $categoryName,
            'applications' => $applicantNumber
        );

        $output = loadTemplate('../Templates/joListing.html.php', $templateVars);
    }
} else {
    $output = loadTemplate('../Templates/login.html.php', []);
}
require '../Templates/layout.html.php';
```

Comment: ok thanks im going to change that However the main issue im having is with the $templateVars part as it keeps saying its undefined I was told that <?= $variable ;?> is the short hand way of writing a php variable on a HTML page

Comment: your $templateVars is inside your If statement, and youre trying to call it in your else statement. You sould move that whole array outside and before the if statement

Comment: so could you tell me where i would need to put it exaclty please (using a snippet of code from above )as i have tried moving it and it didnt seem to work but as im quite new to php maybe im doing it completely wrong

Comment: Actually, you can leave it there and just add another `$output = loadTemplate('../Templates/joListing.html.php', $templateVars);` inside that if statement at the bottom. But your else statement is would still by trying to pull that variable from inside the if statement which it cannot.

Comment: I still seem to get the undefined variable $templateVars which is this line  $output = loadTemplate('../Templates/joListing.html.php', $templateVars);

Comment: I edited my answer, please look.  Make your code that and hopefully it will work.

Comment: yes i realized u edited your answer. Ive tried putting the  $output = loadTemplate('../Templates/jobList.html.php', $templateVars); in the if statement and having it in the else staement aswell that didnt seem to work either i also tried taking it out of the else statement but that didnt work either unfortunately

Comment: yes the answer where you stated "add another $output = loadTemplate('../Templates/joListing.html.php', $templateVars); inside that if statement at the bottom. But your else statement is would still by trying to pull that variable from inside the if statement which it cannot"

Comment: I tried this $templateVars= array(
    'job' => $jobs,
    'category' => $categoryQuery,
    'applicants'=> $applicants,
    'job'=> $filterLocation,
    'categoryQuery'=> $Catname,
    'applicants'=> $applicantCount
   );
   $output = loadTemplate('../Templates/jobList.html.php', $templateVars);
   }
  
   
  else {

 $jobs = findAll($pdo, 'job');

   $output = loadTemplate('../Templates/jobList.html.php', $templateVars);
  
    }

Comment: Not that answer, Look at the MAIN answer the answer we have been commenting on, I posted a whole new block of code.

Comment: Good! That's progress! Maybe change your else statement to this `else {
    $output = loadTemplate('../Templates/login.html.php');
}`